# Tensorflow Implementation for the Numpy dot Product

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Let say I have Vector S0 (length 60) and Matrix E (60 x 60), so when using numpy I can derive the value Z0 as follows:

```
Z0 = S0.getH().dot(E).dot(S0.T);
```

In reality, I have an 2D array Z that has dimensions (D, H), and 3D array S (D, H, M) so I calculate Z as follows:

```
for d in range (D):
  for h in range (H):
     Z[d,h] = S[d,h,:].getH().dot(E).dot(S[d,h,:].T);
```

Is there any way to do this in tensorflow without going through the **for** loops?

Comment: Can you explain what `getH()` does?

Comment: getH() does conjugate transpose - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.getH.html